# Why do i get this traceback error?

Tags: python, py2exe

This is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dwload.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "Pmw\__init__.pyc", line 28, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: "C:\\Users\\P
'sao\\Desktop\\dist\\library.zip\\Pmw/*.*"
```

I get the error after compiling the python file into the executable with py2exe.

Does anybody know why i get this error?

Found the solution: http://billyjin.kodingen.com/punbb-1.3.4/viewtopic.php?id=310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error message says that the path was not found, and if you look at the path, you appear to have mixed up backslashes and slashes as path separators. How are you constructing the path you're using?

Comment: I'm not py2exe did it? I'm not sure i understand.

Comment: I don't know py2exe, but I do know that interpreted Python is quite forgiving when constructing filenames with mixed separators. Possibly py2exe isn't. Look at the files referenced in the tracebacks and find out how the path is constructed. Then correct it so it only uses backslashes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Pmw/*.*,if that's the part your mentioning is to fetch all files in that directories.

Comment: kind of like the glob.glob module

Comment: Of course, but don't you see that it has to be `\\*.*` instead of `/*.*`?

Comment: Yes, i suppose so. How would you suggest i fix this. i cant edit the files because they are all compiled.

Comment: And py2exe compiles it to an executable so i don't really know how i'm supposed to control what it names the files

Comment: If you don't have access to `dwload.py` and possibly other files referenced from there, I don't think you can easily change that.

Comment: No, i do have access to it but at no point in time do i reference the file-path above.

Comment: Obviously you do, otherwise you wouldn't get that error. That path doesn't come from py2exe.

Comment: No i dont. py2exe makes 2 dirs when it runs. one is for the building and the other is dist. in the dist folder there are the files:unicodedata.pyd,tk85.dll,tcl85.dll,select.pyd,python27.dll,library.zip,dwnload.exe,bz2.pyd,_tkinter.pyd,_ssl.pyd,_socket.pyd,_hashlib.pyd,_ctypes.pyd and the tcl folder. The problemes is in the library zipfile that py2exe made.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using pyinstaller and tkinter table (py 2.7). The problem was solved by removing the Pwm dependency in the tkintertable lib metadata. Its will help you, if pwm dont used in program

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution:

First, you need to run the bundlepmw.py in the C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pmw\build\lib\Pmw\Pmw_1_3\bin folder following this command: python bundlepmw.py C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pmw\Pmw_1_3\lib to create the Pmw.py.

Read this page: folk.uio.no/hpl/scripting/doc/python/Pmw/dynamicloader.html, after fixing the bundlepmw.py based on this link sourceforge.net/p/pmw/discussion/33675/thread/f0bd7f34.
You should be able to generate the Pmw.py file.

Then copy the Pmw.py plus PmwBlt.py and PmwColor.py into the main script directory and run your setup.py. Sweet