# Py2exe - Pmw WindowsError: [Error 3]

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe

I am trying to build my standalone executable using Py2exe. I have imported the Pmw class. When I run the stanalone excutable, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "----.py", line 9, in <module>
   File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
   File "Pmw\__init__.pyc", line 28, in <module>

WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\---\\dist\\-----_pmw.exe\\Pmw/*.*'
```

I searched this error, but I was not able to find any solution to it [Why do i get this traceback error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235282/why-do-i-get-this-traceback-error) .

Comment: It seems that I need to run the bundlepmw.py in the C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pmw\build\lib\Pmw\Pmw_1_3\bin folder following this command: python bundlepmw.py C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pmw\Pmw_1_3\lib to create the Pmw.py file and copy PmwBlt.py and PmwColor.py to dist folder.

Comment: Read this page: http://folk.uio.no/hpl/scripting/doc/python/Pmw/dynamicloader.html, after fixing the bundlepmw.py based on this link http://sourceforge.net/p/pmw/discussion/33675/thread/f0bd7f34/, I was able to generate the Pmw.py file, but still get this error WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\...\\dist\\..._pmw.exe\\Pmw/*.*'

Comment: Check this page too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772916/python-pmw-and-cx-freeze . I got the Pmw.py file, but still get the WindowsError.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution:

First, you need to run the bundlepmw.py in the C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pmw\build\lib\Pmw\Pmw_1_3\bin folder following this command: python bundlepmw.py C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pmw\Pmw_1_3\lib to create the Pmw.py.

Read this page: folk.uio.no/hpl/scripting/doc/python/Pmw/dynamicloader.html, after fixing the bundlepmw.py based on this link sourceforge.net/p/pmw/discussion/33675/thread/f0bd7f34. You should be able to generate the Pmw.py file.

Then copy the Pmw.py plus PmwBlt.py and PmwColor.py into the main script directory and run your setup.py. Sweet

Comment: can you actually explain it a bit more, im a beginner, while running the bundle, im getting `usage: bundlepmw.py [-noblt] [-nocolor] /path/to/Pmw/Pmw_X_X_X/lib
`