# can not run the .exe file packed by py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I use windows10,  python 2.7 and PySide 1.2.4.
I have used py2exe0.6.10  to pack a program into exe file.
I could run the program well in IDE. But when I run the exe file. error occurs:

```
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 74, in load_module
  File "PySide\__init__.pyc", line 41, in <module>
  File "PySide\__init__.pyc", line 11, in _setupQtDirectories
  File "PySide\_utils.pyc", line 97, in get_pyside_dir
  File "PySide\_utils.pyc", line 88, in _get_win32_case_sensitive_name
  File "PySide\_utils.pyc", line 63, in _get_win32_short_name
  WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have also tried another computer with windows7 but the same error occurs.

Comment: Try this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29478340/2570277). He also had python 2.7

Comment: My problem arise from pyside, which is different from him.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably unhelpful, but have you tried to delete the package then reinstall it?

This probably won't help :) but give it a try.

mgmc2

Comment: I have tried to uninstall pyside1.2.2 and reinstall 1.2.4 but the same error occurs.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what else to do! I don't know everything about Python. Hope you work it out.